# Unable to Select Value from Dataset

Tags: filtering, dataset

I'm doing a project using one of the datasets in the Wolfram Data Repository, and I ran into a weird wall that I have not been able to fix.

I imported the dataset like this:

`COVIDData = ResourceData[ResourceObject["Coronavirus COVID-19 Pandemic Government Measures"]]`

Then, using the select function, I should be able to select various countries based on their respective values in the dataset. For example, I can select all the rows with the UNCode "AFG", and get an implementation date:

`Normal[COVIDData[Select[#UNCode == "AFG" &]][All,"ImplementationDate"]]`

Filtering by UNCode works fine, however some of the others columns I filter by mysteriously give me a white box, even though the code should be correct. In particular, trying to filter by Country, Region, and Continent all give me a blank white box as an output:

`Normal[COVIDData[Select[#Country== "Afghanistan" &]][All,"ImplementationDate"]]`

`Normal[COVIDData[Select[#Region== "Asia" &]][All,"ImplementationDate"]]`

`Normal[COVIDData[Select[#Continent== "Asia" &]][All,"ImplementationDate"]]`

The 3 code lines above all give a blank white box. I've tried doing a bunch of different things, all of them ending up in that blank white box. Is this a problem with the dataset, or is there another approach to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: The values of Country, Region and Continent are not strings. Instead, they are entities, which you can see if you try `Normal@COVIDData[2, {"Country", "Region", "Continent"}] // InputForm`

Comment: So, for example, `Normal[COVIDData[Select[#Country == Entity["Country",  "Afghanistan"] &]][All, "ImplementationDate"]]` gets the ImplementationDate data for Afghanistan.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: The blank white box means an empty `Dataset` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Country` attribute is a [`"Country"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Country.html) [`Enitiy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Enitiy.html).

```
Normal[COVIDData[
   Select[#Country == Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"] &]][All,"ImplementationDate"]]
```

The `Region` and `Continent` attributes are `"Country"` [`EntityClass`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityClass.html)es.

```
Normal[COVIDData[Select[#Region == EntityClass["Country", "Asia"] &]][All, "ImplementationDate"]]

Normal[COVIDData[
   Select[#Continent == EntityClass["Country", "Asia"] &]][All, "ImplementationDate"]]
```

See the [Enter Free-Form Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterFreeFormInput.html) workflow for keyboard shortcuts to enter these. For example, for Asian `"Country"` `EntityClass` you can type:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> Asian Continent <kbd>Enter</kbd> *(not numpad Enter)*

instead of the input form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!